# Is expectation of the product of two cards with replacement larger than without replacement

Tags: probability, expected-value

> > We have 10 cards numbered from 1 to 10. We pick two cards among them. What is the expected value of the product of these two cards with and without replacement?

My thought:
Let X and Y be the number on the two card
For with replacement, X and Y are independent, so E(X*Y)=E(X)*E(Y)=30.25

For without replacement, since X and Y are dependent, I feel it is the same, but could not think a nice way to prove it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Consider that in the two-card case, the average without replacement is $2$, while the average with replacement is $9/4 \not= 2$.

Comment: P.S. In general, the average without replacement is $\frac{(3n+2)(n+1)}{12}$, while the average with replacement is $\frac{(3n+3)(n+1)}{12}$, so it can be seen that the latter is greater, by a margin of $\frac{n+1}{12}$. When I get a chance, I'll post a more extensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with replacement, $P(X=n,Y=k)=\frac{1}{90}$ for $n\neq k$, so the measure is still uniform. This makes the calculation not all that different since we just have to account for the contribution of the diagonal terms where $n=k$. In other words,

$$
\begin{align*}
E(XY)&=\frac{1}{90}\sum_{1\leq k\neq n\leq 10} nk \\
\\
&=\frac{1}{90}\left(\sum_{1\leq k,n\leq 10} nk-\sum_{j=1}^{10} j^2\right)\\
\\
&=\frac1{90}\left(\binom{11}{2}^2-\frac{10\cdot11\cdot 21}{6}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{88}3.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks! so E(X,Y) for without replacement is 88/3, so is smaller than with replacement